# substring or print the array upto num of position in C++

Tags: c++, cout, substr

In PHP I remember I can do something like

`substr(string,start,length)`

now I declare

`int array[20];`

how can I print only a part of it without using a for loop

for example.

`cout << array[1 to 5] << "Here is the breaking point" << array[15 to 20] << endl;`

Something like this

I also remember if it was `printf` there would be something like `^5` or something like saying upto 5

Comment: You can use the [pretty printer](http://louisdx.github.com/cxx-prettyprint/): `std::cout << pretty_print_array(array + 3, 6) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of `ostream_iterator` and `copy` ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/1xwbb)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
    ostream_iterator<int> out_it (cout," ");
    copy ( array+3, array+6, out_it );
    return 0;
}
```

The `array+3` syntax may look unusual: this is a pointer expression equivalent to `&array[3]`, which produces a pointer. Since you can pass a pair of array pointers where  C standard library expects a pair of iterators, this produces the expected results.

Answer (score 3):

You could copy to an ostream iterator:

```
std::copy(array, array+5, std::ostream_iterator(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << "Here is the breaking point";
std::copy(array+15, array+20, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```